# Sign In with Apple with Firebase - invalid IDP token/credential. Working on simulator but not live device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, apple-sign-in

I have an app enabling email/password, Google, Apple, and anonymous sign in methods with Firebase as the backend.

Interestingly, signing in on the simulator with all methods is successful. On my live device (using the same AppleID as the simulator), I get an error .invalidCredential. From Firebase docs "Indicates the IDP token or requestUri is invalid."

The simulator is running iOS 16.2 and my iPhone iOS 17. I'm not sure why I'm getting the discrepancy in success with the Apple SSO. The other sign in methods work fine on both devices.

This is my sign in Apple flow. Its being called with

```
    func signInApple() async throws {
        let helper = SignInAppleHelper()
        let tokens = try await helper.startSignInWithAppleFlow()
        let authDataResult = try await AuthenticationManager.shared.signInWithApple(tokens:  tokens)
        let user = DBUser(auth: authDataResult)
        try await UserManager.shared.createNewUser(user: user)
    }
```

And this is the helper

```
struct SignInWithAppleResult {
    let token: String
    let nonce: String
    let name: String?
    let email: String?
}

struct SignInWithAppleButtonViewResentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let type: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.ButtonType
    let style: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.Style
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: type, style: style)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

@MainActor
final class SignInAppleHelper: NSObject {
   
    private var currentNonce: String?
    private var completionHandler: ((Result<SignInWithAppleResult, Error>) -> Void)? = nil

    func startSignInWithAppleFlow() async throws -> SignInWithAppleResult {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.startSignInWithAppleFlow { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let signInAppleResult):
                    continuation.resume(returning: signInAppleResult)
                    return
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startSignInWithAppleFlow(completion: @escaping (Result<SignInWithAppleResult, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let topVC = Utilities.shared.topViewController() else {
            completion(.failure(URLError(.badURL)))
            return
        }
        
      let nonce = randomNonceString()
      currentNonce = nonce
      completionHandler = completion
        
      let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
      let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
      request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
      request.nonce = sha256(nonce)

      let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
      authorizationController.delegate = self
      authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = topVC
      authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
    
    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
      precondition(length > 0)
      var randomBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
      let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, randomBytes.count, &randomBytes)
      if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
        fatalError(
          "Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)"
        )
      }

      let charset: [Character] =
        Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")

      let nonce = randomBytes.map { byte in
        // Pick a random character from the set, wrapping around if needed.
        charset[Int(byte) % charset.count]
      }

      return String(nonce)
    }
   
    @available(iOS 13, *)
    private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
      let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
      let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
      let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        String(format: "%02x", $0)
      }.joined()

      return hashString
    }
}

extension SignInAppleHelper: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        
        guard
            let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential,
            let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken,
            let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8),
            let nonce = currentNonce else {
            completionHandler?(.failure(URLError(.badServerResponse)))
            print("APPLE SIGN IN FAILED")
            return
        }
        
        let name = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
        let email = appleIDCredential.email
        
        let tokens = SignInWithAppleResult( token: idTokenString, nonce: nonce, name: name, email: email)
        completionHandler?(.success(tokens))
        
        func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
            // Handle error.
            print("Sign in with Apple errored: \(error)")
            completionHandler?(.failure(firebaseErrorHandler(error: error as NSError) as! Error))
        }
        
    }
}

extension UIViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    public func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return self.view.window!
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Cant find a resolution anywhere